# Why is Eclipse wrongly finding spelling errors in Ruby comments?

Tags: ruby, eclipse, spell-checking

I am using the 3.7.1 version of the Eclipse SDK, and it is flagging up every word in my Ruby comments as being misspelled.

This is not happening in, say, JavaScript or HTML files, even when viewed in the Ruby perspective.

The comments are being shown in the correct colour, so the IDE is definitely aware of what they are.

Any idea how I can fix this behaviour (apart from switching off spell checking)?

Comment: works fine for me on eclipse 3.6. i am using Aptana plugin..

Comment: Could you add the information what plugins you have installed additionally? I cannot reproduce that with Eclipse Indigo (Java), DLTK-RDT 3.0.0.

Comment: What plugins are used to edit HTML and JavaScript files? Without a proper HTML editor, tags like `html` are flagged as not-valid English.

Comment: What information exactly do you want? And how can I find it in Eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never worked out what the problem was. However, I've just reinstalled eclipse from scratch, and the problems's gone away.

Previously I had the classic Java installation with the Aptana Ruby plug-in. Now I'm using the [JavaScript for Web Developers IDE](http://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-javascript-web-developers/indigosr1), with 'Dynamic Languages Toolkit - Ruby Development Tools' added.